# All possible continuous maps from unit disc in complex numbers.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D$ be a unit disc, i.e., $D=\{x\in \mathbb{C}: |z|<1\}$. Let $f:\bar{D}\to \mathbb{C}$ be a continuous function. Suppose $f\big|_D$ is holomorphic, $|f(z)|=1$ for every $z\in \partial D$ and $f$ vanishes at exactly one point $a\in D$. Assume that $a\in (-1, 1)$ and $f(1)=1$. Find all functions $f$ having the above-said properties.

My Attempt: I know that if I take
$$f(z)=\frac{z-a}{1-az}$$ then
$f(a)=0, f(1)=1$ and $|f(z)|=1$ for every $z\in \partial D$.
This choice of $f$ fulfills the given condition. How to look for other choices and how to get all such functions?

Comment: It also includes functions of the form $e^{i\theta} (f(z))^n$.

Comment: If it is holomorphic it is possible to use Taylor sequence and search solutions in infinite polynomyals

Comment: For the case $a = 0$, then you can use the [Schwarz lemma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma). Maybe you can use some transformation to take the general case to that specific one?

Comment: @ArcticChar Since $f(1)=1$, so it includes $(f(z))^n$. But how to ensure that no other functions are there?

Comment: @BrunoB How it is possible as it is not given that $f:D\to D$?

Comment: The maximum principle tells you that.

Comment: If the order of vanishing at $a$ is $k\ge 1$ then $g=f/(\phi_a)^k$ still satisfies $|g|=1$ on the unit circle but now doesn't vanish inside and is holomorphic so maximum modulus applied to $g,1/g$ shows it is constant of modulus $1$ and then use the condition $f(1)=1$ etc (here $\phi_a=(z-a)/(1-az)$ is the corresponding disc automorphism like in the OP